# проблема preference в fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-preferences

Подчеркивает FindPreference, getSharedPreferences.
Необходимо перенести из активити во фрагмент, но не получается

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
        Preference customPref = (Preference) rootView.findPreference("customPref");
        customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "The custom preference has been clicked",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                                "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference
                                .edit();
                        editor.putString("myCustomPref",
                                "The preference has been clicked");
                        editor.apply();
                        return true;
                    }

                });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что метод `getSharedPreferences` это метод контекста, а вы вызываете его у фрагмента.

```
SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                                "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: может getActivity()

Comment: Активность наследуется от Контекста, поэтому мы можем вызвать getSharedPreferences хоть как